# data set to json with group

Tags: sql, angularjs, json, node.js, tedious

I am working on an angular + nodejs application and I need some data from sql in json format. I am able to get the data in json but I need the data to be grouped in a tree like manner. Is there a way to do this in sql, server or in front end level?

**Data I have in table**

[image: Data I have in Table]

---

**What I currently get**

```
{"":[
    "3",
    "6",
    "12"
 ],
"":[
    "3",
    "6",
    "13"
  ],
"":  [
    "3",
    "7",
    "16"
  ],
"":  [
    "3",
    "7",
    "17"
  ],
"":  [
    "3",
    "8",
    "18"
  ],
"":  [
    "3",
    "8",
    "19"
  ],
"":  [
    "3",
    "9",
    "20"
  ],
"":  [
    "3",
    "9",
    "21"
  ]
 }
```

---

**What I want in json:**

```
{"" :{ "3": {"6": ["12", "13"], "7": ["16", "17"], "8": ["18", "19"], "9": [ "20", "21" ]} }}
```

Please suggest a way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post an example of how it's returning now?

Comment: @kauffee000 updated with sample data

Comment: That doesn't seem to be valid JSON though. I was going to suggest looping through and building your own object based on a JSON response.

Comment: @kauffee000 I just made that data, actual data looks something similar to this. Can you suggest on `building your own object`? is there a library for this?

Comment: I'd just loop through and make a little transform function with Javascript. But what you want and what you have posted as an example isn't a valid Javascript object OR valid JSON. Why does it have to be that format?

Comment: This is valid:

`{
  "3": {
    "6": ["12", "13"],
    "7": ["16", "17"],
    "8": ["18", "19"]
  },
  "9": [
      "20",
      "21"
    ]
};`

Comment: The data you currently get is not a valid json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to get your data as valid json like below:

```
var items = [
    {
        l0: "3",
        l1: "6",
        l2: "12"
    },
    {
        l0: "3",
        l1: "6",
        l2: "13"
    },
    {
        l0: "3",
        l1: "7",
        l2: "16"
    },
    {
        l0: "3",
        l1: "7",
        l2: "17"
    },
    {
        l0: "3",
        l1: "8",
        l2: "18"
    },
    {
        l0: "3",
        l1: "8",
        l2: "19"
    },
    {
        l0: "3",
        l1: "9",
        l2: "20"
    },
    {
        l0: "3",
        l1: "9",
        l2: "21"
    }
  ];
```

Then you can get what you want by:

```
var result = {};
items.forEach(item => {
    result[item.l0] = result[item.l0] || {};
    result[item.l0][item.l1] = result[item.l0][item.l1] || [];
    result[item.l0][item.l1].push(item.l2); 
});

console.log(result);
```

Final result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your SQL query results by multiple columns, this should return the data in the order you are looking for:

```
<original_query> + ORDER BY c1, c2, c3
```

Comment: the order is not the issue, I can sort it accordingly but I want some way to group it like I shown in json. May be it is not possible in SQL but I just wanted to check.